# Angular Testing: "Expected a spy, but got Function" in Capacitor Browser Plugin

Tags: angular, unit-testing, capacitor

I have many problems with unit testing in Angular, is my first time making unit testing.
Well, I have an error on Browser plugin testing:

```
Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
```

On my component I just have this:

```
    async goToPage(path: string) {
        let url_ = environment.apiUrl + path;
        await Browser.open({url : url_,presentationStyle: 'popover'})
    }
```

and tried to resolve this by many ways:

```
it('should use In App Browser', () => {
    const browser = Browser;
    const spy = spyOn(browser,'open');
    const url = '/api/resource/TOS';
    component.goToPage(url);
    expect(spy.call).toHaveBeenCalled();
}); 

it('should use In App Browser', () => {
    spyOn(Browser,'open');
    expect(Browser.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
//Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.


it('should use In App Browser', () => {
    const browser = Browser;
    spyOn(browser,'open');
    expect(browser.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
//Expected a spy, but got Function.


it('should use In App Browser', () => {
    const browser = Browser;
    spyOn(browser,'open').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());;
    expect(browser.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
//Expected a spy, but got Function.


it('should use In App Browser', async() => {
    const browser = Browser;
    spyOn(browser, 'open')

    expect(browser.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
//Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
//Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()


it('should use In App Browser', async() => {
  const browser = Browser;
  spyOn(browser, 'open')
  expect(await browser.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
//Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.


it('should create', (done) => {
  let browser = Browser;
  spyOn<any>(browser, 'open');
  const url_ = environment.apiUrl + '/api/resource/About';
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(browser.open).toHaveBeenCalled();   expect(browser.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith({url : url_,presentationStyle: 'popover'});
      done();
  });
});
//Unhandled promise rejection: Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
//Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Do you know some way to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this official guide: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/mocking-plugins
You have to create a `__mocks__/@capacitor` folder (see [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/mocking-plugins#jasmine)).